# Numerical approximation of the Jacobian matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Is there an approximation of the Jacobian Matrix given an ODE which can only be solved numerically?

That means I have a system of ODEs $\dot{x}_i=f_i(x(t),t))$ and one objective function $g(x(t))$ . I need the Jacobian with respect to $g(x(t))$. In short: $\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}$

I have a system of ODEs with no analytical solution but I need the Jacobian matrix at fixed time points.

I do not need the exact solution but an fast algorithm.

Comment: You need to provide a little more information. The Jacobian of what?

Comment: What does the Jacobian of $g$ have to do with the ODE? (I'm trying to figure out what you are asking.)